# Chat in Minecraft PS4 Edition

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm not sure if I have the Better Together update, but I don't know how to enable chat and I need to insert a command block in my PS4 world.

Comment: Try following this video and post the results:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGIsc54foCM

Comment: Have you watched it? Because it tells how to use the voice chat, not game chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PS4 does not have command blocks into it and you cannot chat. The beta together update was for xboxs and Mobile devices. The only way to do some commands is.

1. From the menu screen go onto the world that you would like to do commands in.
2. press "More Options"
3. Press "Game Options"
4. Make sure Host Privileges is on.
5. Now load up the world and press the big middle button on your controller and there's options. You cannot chat though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't chat, and no command blocks exist in any of the console versions. But, there exists a way to use commands. First, make sure that Host Privileges is on. Game Options should have it on your worlds. In the world, press Select (Or Touchpad for the PS4 players) and go to Host Options. You'll find some gamerules and commands, including teleportation and time. If you want other players to be able to use commands, make them a moderator by going to them and pressing X (PS3/PS4, for XBOX i dunno). You'll see the option to kick them out and set their spawn point, along with the moderator option. Highlight the moderator checkbox and confirm it. You have to do the same to other players if you want others to be a moderator too.